# Populate array with incremental values topping grand total

Tags: c#, arrays, probability

I have an array of floats that would be declared with a variable length. I would like to have a loop that would assign to each element a value proportioned to its position in the array, and the grand total of all the elements should be fixed (to 100).

```
int arrLength = 5; //this would variate
float grandTotal = 100; //the sum of all the elements should be equal to this
float[] arr = new float[arrLength]();

for(int i=1; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    //logic to attribute values to the elements
}
```

What I want to achieve is for the elements to represent probabilistic values (in %). The idea is that the lower the index the higher the value they have. So for instance if the length would be equal to 5 the output array should have values like:

```
arr={30, 25, 20, 15, 10};
```

As you can see the values are decreasing and total of them is 100. I could I get this type of result regardless of the length of the array?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you're asking here. Can you edit your question to include sample input and output?

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*, e.g for `arrLength` equals to `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: Do you need data to be randomized?

Comment: may I ask why are you voting this down..?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to implement Arithmetic progression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Arithmetic progression has to parameters, start element *a0* and difference *d*.
In your case, the sum of arithmetic progression is *grandTotal*.
Here we have two unknown variables: *a0* and *d*. 
To handle this, we should play with different assumptions.

1. We could suppose that a0 = d.
   In this case 
   d = 2*grandTotal/(n*(2+n-1)) 
   (n is arrLength). 
   In your example it will be 2*200/(5*(5+1)) = 6.666666666..., and elements will be 6.66666666, 13.33333333333, 20, 26.666666666, 33.3333333333.
   Looks not very pretty.
   We could suppose that a0 = 2*d. In this case d = 5 (formula will be d = 2*grandTotal/(n*(2*2+n-1))), and progression is 10, 15, 20, 25, 30.
   So, you should implement two loops. First should try different assumptions, e.g. a0 = d, a0 = 2*d, a0 = 3*d, to find "pretty" difference. And then, iterate to fill and array.
2. We could suppose that a0 = sqrt(grandTotal). In this case d = (2*grandTotal/n-2*a[0])/(n-1) (in your example, it will produce 10, 15, 20, 25, 30).

You may start with second way.

When you get *a0* and *n*, the loop looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    arr[i] = a0 + d*(n-i-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arrLength = 5;
float grandTotal = 100; 
float[] arr = new float[arrLength];

int arrLengthInc = arrLength + 1;
int sum = (arrLengthInc * arrLengthInc / 2) + (arrLengthInc / 2) - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = (i + 2) * grandTotal / sum;
}

// output: // [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", arr));
```

You need to determine the sum of the whole array, for normalize them.

for example:
2 + 3 + 4 = 9

```
+-+-+-+-+
| | | |/|
+-+-+-+-+
| | |/|#|
+-+-+-+-+
| |/|#|#|
+-+-+-+-+
|/|#|#|#|
+-+-+-+-+  4*4 / 2 = 0.5 + 1.5 + 2.5 + 3.5 = 8


The items on the diagonal consume half space.
+-+-+-+-+
| | | |#|
+-+-+-+-+
| | |#|#|
+-+-+-+-+
| |#|#|#|
+-+-+-+-+
|#|#|#|#|
+-+-+-+-+  (4*4 / 2) + (4 / 2) = 0.5 + 1.5 + 2.5 + 3.5 = 10

Index one is missing.
+-+-+-+-+
| | | |#|
+-+-+-+-+
| | |#|#|
+-+-+-+-+
| |#|#|#|
+-+-+-+-+
| |#|#|#|
+-+-+-+-+  (4*4 / 2) + (4 / 2) - 1 = 0.5 + 1.5 + 2.5 + 3.5 = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[arr.Length -1 - i] = ((i+2) * arrLength)%grandTotal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//sum of array length elements

int factor=((arrLength*arrlength)+arrLength)/2;

.......

ar[i]=grandTotal/factor*(arrLength-i+1);